# Accessing image data (from `<img>` element) on permitted webpage through content scripts with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to view image data on a webpage my extension has listed under `"permissions":[...]`.

Doesn't matter if it's exported as some sort of Base64 blob or raw pixel array, as long as it's 'reversible'(!!) in the sense that the content script can decipher the contents with relative accuracy.

I've tried a lot of things, none of which worked. I tried rendering it to a Canvas followed by a call to `toDataURL`, but then it complained about the canvas being 'tainted'. I also tried re-fetching the image and encode it with `FileReader.readAsDataURL`, which got me `"data:"`, so I don't know what else there is to do.

Should be noted that I've also added the CDN of the website I'm working with under permitted sites, even tried `"<all_urls>"`, to no avail.. I've tried fetching with `"no-cors"`, which didn't work either. I can't tell why this is such an issue -- I mean the data is literally on display, why can't an extension (with ample permissions) observe it? I mean there are extensions that can take screenshots of webpages for crying out loud -- what's the trick?

Comment: The trick is to use Canvas in your extension's script, not in the web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm I already tried. As mentioned, tried rendering it to a canvas in my content script, but always met with an error similar to `Access to image at 'https://some.dns.service' from origin 'https://actual.website' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` despite adding 'https://some.dns.service' to `"permissions:"`.. any other ideas?

Comment: I said "not in web page" and I meant the background script or the popup script and so on.

Comment: @wOxxOm how are you supposed to transfer an image from a webpage to a background script when you cannot even serialize it!?

Comment: Load the image element's `src` in the extension page as a `new Image` or via `fetch` + `createImageBitmap`. Then render it to Canvas.

Comment: @wOxxOm Well, I see why that would that work, but do you really have to fetch the resource TWICE for the extension to also access the data?

Comment: Images will be cached in many cases. Anyway, the alternatives aren't good for various reasons: chrome.debugger API (the same thing devtools uses internally) or making a screenshot of the page via chrome.tabCapture (obviously imprecise and totally wrong if the image is scaled).